# gtkmm 4.0 header build errors when compiling own project

Tags: cmake, gtkmm, gtkmm4

I recently updated my gtkmm framework to version 4.0.0 and updated code to be compatible with the framework. I'm using msys2 in JetBrains CLion on Windows. However when I'm compiling project I got wall of warnings and errors in various framework headers like gtkmm, glibmm etc. I can't find errors which could be related to my code. Here is my Cmake configurations

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.17.5)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS " -lstdc++fs")
project (Accounter)
find_package(Boost 1.73 COMPONENTS date_time REQUIRED)
FIND_LIBRARY (LIBZIP_LIBRARY NAMES zip)
FIND_PATH (LIBZIP_INCLUDE_DIR zip.h PATH_SUFFIXES include/zip include ) # Find header
INCLUDE(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)

FIND_PACKAGE(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(GTKMM gtkmm-4.0)
include_directories( ${GTKMM_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
link_directories( ${GTKMM_LIBRARY_DIRS} )
#ADD_DEFINITIONS(${GTK_CFLAGS_OTHER})

FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS(libzip  DEFAULT_MSG  LIBZIP_LIBRARY LIBZIP_INCLUDE_DIR)
link_directories((Accounting))
add_subdirectory(Accounting)
link_directories(OdsFile)
add_subdirectory(OdsFile)
link_directories(GUI)
add_subdirectory(GUI)
if(Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    add_executable(Accounter main.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(Accounter LINK_PUBLIC Accounting OdsFile GUI ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${LIBZIP_LIBRARY} stdc++fs ${GTKMM_LIBRARIES} )
else()
    message( FATAL_ERROR "Boost library is required for this library")
ENDIF().
```

The compile log is under [this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/alhqrftesvipj4o/Build%20errors.txt?dl=0) . Do I miss something in cmake configuration? How it should be compiled? I'll provide additional info, files if it will be required. I think errors should be on my side not on framework.

Comment: ...why are you calling `find_package_handle_standard_args`? It's only useful in a find module, which this is not.

Comment: Fair point. When creating project I had problem with adding libzip to project and found somewhere cmake code for libzip. I'm improving adding libzip. However the main issue is strange compilation problems with gtkmm 4.0 .